# Regular expression to skipped punctuation, but except @{digit}

Tags: regex

Currently I am using `[^\w\d]` to look for all punctuation, and replace it with a space.

Example:
`The quick brown fox jumps ~!@# over the lazy dog`
becomes
`The quick brown fox jumps      over the lazy dog`

It is working fine, but sometimes there is certain condition like `@{100}`.

`The quick brown fox jumps ~!@# over @{100} the lazy dog`
should become:
`The quick brown fox jumps      over @{100} the lazy dog`

Without screwing up the `@{100}`. Anyone can help? The pattern is always `@{digit}`.

Comment: What is the regex library/engine/flavor? Note that `[^\w\d]` = `\W`. Have you tried anything yet, BTW?

Comment: It is important that you add a language tag since, e.g. [this solution](https://regex101.com/r/l1TxX1/1), will only work with PCRE.

Comment: i am using .net

Comment: Just to precise: have you got access to the code? Run `Regex.Replace` with a match evaluator? Please post it if you have.

Comment: it will be like:

private static readonly Regex PunctuationRegex = new Regex(@"[^\w\s]");
PunctuationRegex.Replace(keyword, " ");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET regex, there is no way ti skip matches, nor does it support conditional replacement patterns that would enable a pure regex solution. You need to match and capture `@{digits}` part and match non-word (and I believe it is best to also exclude whitespaces from this pattern) chars. Then, check what group matched, and replace accordingly:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(@{[0-9]+})|[^\w\s]", m => 
            m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : " ");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/AmEpk7):

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumps ~!@# over @{100} the lazy dog";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(@{[0-9]+})|[^\w\s]", m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : " ");
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => The quick brown fox jumps      over @{100} the lazy dog
```

**Details**

- `(@{[0-9]+})` - Group 1: `@{`, 1 or more digits, `}`
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - any char that is not a word and not a whitespace char
- `m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Value : " "` - if Group 1 matches, put back the whole match, else, replace with a single regular space.

Comment: Ya, thanks a lot. i just placed in ur code and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead and lookbehind to break down your criteria into cases, like this:

`[^\w\d\s@\{\}]+|@(?!\{\d+\})|(?<!@)\{(?!\{\d+\})|(?<!@{\d+)\}`

there are four cases here, they will match:

- All punctuation except `@`, `{`, `}`
- The `@` character, only if not followed by   `\{\d+\}`
- The `{` character, only if not preceded by `@` and not followed by `\{\d+\}`
- The `}` character, only if not preceded by `{\d+`

This last part is possible since you use .NET.
.NET regex engine supports non-fixed width negative lookbehind (this is supported by .NET but not by many other regex engines).